# Ghost CD drive not listed in Disk manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a CD/DVD combo drive on my laptop for several years and it has always been listed as a single drive in Windows 10 (F:).  For some reason, a new CD drive did appear as a new drive, taking out the D: letter which was used for one of my SSD drive.  My SSD drive now as the E: letter but I would like to reassign the D letter to it.

I don't understand why but the new CD drive is visible in windows explorer but it isn't listed in the Disk manager.  I tried to disable/uninstall the device but this only had effect on the DVD F: drive.

I tried to solve this in DOS but the D: drive is visible from the wmic command line:

```
wmic logicaldisk get name
```

but it isn't visible from DISKPART (list volume)

Does anyone what can make a volume visible in windows explorer but hidden in the disk manager?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually impossible for a drive to have a letter in File Explorer but not in Disk Management.

If a volume can’t be see in DISPART list volume command, we can’t do any operation to remove its letter.

Maybe you could simply, from within disk mgmt, select the drive, right-click, change drive letter & hit the Remove tab